# How to remove http://IP_ASDRESS/index.php/xyz from laravel 5?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5, digital-ocean

I know that question has been answered number of times, but I would like to tell you what I did but still I haven't manage to remove it.

Firstly I'm hosting my app on digital ocean with apache 2, and I double check that the mod_rewrite is activated. Also I add on my htaccess in the public folder the following

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

on the index.php I have the following lines

```
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/start.php';
$app->run();
```

After doing this configurations I couldn't remove the index.php/xyz.

I would like to ask if I'm doing something wrong or if I'm missing something.

Ps. the http://IP_ADDRESS is working fine with the home page.
PSS. I restart the apache 2 serval times.

Comment: You don't have to change anything from the default `.htaccess` and `index.php`. The only thing you need to do is point your document root to `/public`

Comment: I did that, but only the http://IP_Address is working not the http://IP_ADDRESS/xyz also if i want to see xyz I have to add before that the index.php. By the way I'm using laravel 5